# Derivative of vector matrix multipication by element of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, symmetric-matrices

Linking to a question that I previously asked ([Differentiate expressions involving symmetric matrix $\mathbf{D}=\mathrm{diag}(\tau)\Omega\mathrm{diag}(\tau)$ with respect to element of $\tau$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473761/differentiate-expressions-involving-symmetric-matrix-mathbfd-mathrmdiag)), I now find that I need to find the value of the following:

$$
\frac{d(\mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathbf{b})}{db_{g}}
$$

In the above, $\mathbf{D}^{-1}$ is the inverse of a symmetric $q$ by $q$ covariance matrix, and $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector of length $q$.  I want to differentiate the expression with respect to the $g$th element of $\mathbf{b}$.

I can see (e.g. using equation 85 in matrix cookbook https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf how to find the value of the above if differentiating by $\mathbf{b}$, but cannot see a clear step-by-step explanation for a single element $b_g$.  Any guidance / help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

*Background: This stems from manipulating a multivariate normal distribution for parameter $\mathbf{b}$ with mean vector equal to vector of zeros and covariance matrix equal to $\mathbf{D}$.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(b) = b^TD^{-1}b$. From the equation you mention, we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = 2D^{-1}b.
$$
Note that this assumes that $D$ is symmetric (which applies in your case because $D$ is a covariance matrix) and that $D$ is independent of $b$.

Since we're taking a derivative with respect to a column-vector, extracting the individual partial derivative is simple.  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b_g}$ is just the $g$th entry of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}$.  In particular: let $e_g$ denote the $g$th column of the size $q$ identity matrix. We have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = e_g^T(2D^{-1}b) = 2(e_g^TD^{-1})b.
$$
Note that $e_g^T D^{-1}$ is the $g$th row of $D^{-1}$.